# Only show last 5 days records in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with a simple PHP query that return records from a MYSQL table without issue.

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM $shopname
```

I am trying to figure out how to only return the last 5 days of records based on a field called "date". The date field is a VARCHAR type in mysql. The format of the dates in the date field are like this: **8/9/2016 5:52:17 PM**. I did try the following query from some researching, but this doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM $shopname WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)");
```

*IMPORTANT - I can't change mysql field to DATE. It has to be VARCHAR.

Comment: Please change the type of the `date` column into `date`. Then you can use functions that are meant to be used with dates (not characters).

Comment: _Never_ store dates in a `varchar`.  This is why the query isn't returning anything.

Comment: Try with `NOW()` -> `WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)")` and change your date column to `timestamp`

Comment: Please learn how to search. Maybe next time. Cheers.

Comment: The issue is that I import a CSV file into this field and the dates don't import if I change to DATE type

Comment: if I import my CSV with the field as DATE type it imports all 0's like 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` here for VARCHAR date format:

**Example:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $shopname 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) < 5";
```

`STR_TO_DATE()` for DateFormat, will use to compare `date` with `CURDATE()`.

`DATEDIFF()` for DateDiff, will use to get date difference in between `date` and `current date`.

*But, it's better to use `MYSQL Date format`, instead of `VARCHAR` field.*

Comment: still no result

Comment: @MariaNolorbe: its better to use DATE format or you can also control it from PHP

Comment: I would love to use DATE format, but I'm at the mercy of a CSV file that is formatted like: 8/9/2016 5:52:17 PM.

Comment: @MariaNolorbe: alright, u can also control it from php

Comment: @MariaNolorbe: you can also check the duplicate links

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your vatchar date column is formatted  as dd-mm-yyyy you shuold convert in  date this way

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, 
    " SELECT * 
      FROM $shopname 
      WHERE str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')  >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE t.date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Provide the `date` should be if the char-type as `date`

Or else you can use this method to retrieve the data for last 5 days.

```
SELECT name,date 
from TABLE
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method by mysql UNIX_TIMESTAMP.this can change time to timestamp!

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM $shopname WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(8/9/2016 5:52:17 PM)");
```